# Iterate array and make service call and store the response in array

Tags: javascript, ajax

`WordId` is an array. I want to iterate an array and make service call and store the response in `responses` array.

```
var wordId = [];
var responses = [];

for (var i = 0; i < result.words.length; i++) {
if (result.words[i].exampleSentences == undefined) {
wordId.push(result.words[i].identifier);
}
}

self.getWordExample(0, wordId, responses, function(responses) {
                console.log(responses);
            });
            console.log("outside",responses);
```

My service file

```
getWordExample: function(i, wordId, responses,callback) {
    var self = this;
    services.WordExampleService.getWordExamples(wordId[i], function(err, response) {
        responses.push(response);
        i++;
        if (wordId[i]) {
            console.log("wordid",wordId[i]);
            self.getWordExample(i, wordId, responses);
        } 
        else if(callback){
            console.log(responses);
            callback(responses);
        }
    });
}
```

[image]

This is the console.Why the service is executing first and wordid is executing next
Is there any way to execute the function first and then return the `responses`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call it in a recursive async way:

```
function callService(wordIdIndex, callback) {
    services.WordExampleService.getWordExamples(wordId[wordIdIndex], function(err, response) {
        responses.push(response);

        wordIdIndex++;
        if (wordId[wordIdIndex]) {
            callService(wordIdIndex);
        }
        else if (callback) {
            callback(responses);
        }
    });
}

 callService(0, function(responses) {
     console.log(responses);
 });
```

Use this code instead of the second `for` statement.

Remember, as your requests are async, everything which relies on `responses` should be executed inside that callback for now on.

Comment: Ur code is working the problem is I want to return the `responses` array and and capture the `callservice` function returned value and I have to iterate the `reponses` array. the for loop is executing before the function `callservice`

Comment: @akshayarathinavel Ok, chcke the update. I have added a callback.

Comment: I will update my question one more time I have a problem with the service call. Please have a look into it.

Comment: @akshayarathinavel that is because the request is **async**. You should take a research about it to understand the concept, that is why you are so confused. As I said in the last paragraph in my post, **everything** you need to do with `responses` **have** to be inside that callback.

Comment: yeah, I know it is **async** , See my question I have changed. But I don't want to do anything inside the callback. I want the `responses` outside the callback. Is there any way or method to do

Comment: @akshayarathinavel no my friend, there is not way to do so. The responses will be available **only** inside the callback. cheers.

Comment: Thanks for your reply